# How to retrieve the password of an AWS custom AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've recently made an AMI from an important server instance I had. Recently, I made an AMI out of that instance, and then deleted it in order to save space. Now, I'm trying to make an instance from that custom AMI, and in-order to connect to it I need the old password(For some reason that is what it requires). I still own the .pem keypair file needed to decode the password, however it wont let me get and de-crypt the key.

What should i do in order to get the password of the custom AMI?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a **Windows instance**, you can follow these directions in the Amazon EC2 documentation: [Resetting an Administrator Password that's Lost or Expired](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-passwords.html#ResettingAdminPassword).

The process uses another EC2 instance to access the disk to modify a configuration setting, allowing you to retrieve a new password.

Basically, the steps are:

- **Stop** the "original" instance
- **Launch** a "temporary" instance
- **Detach** the boot volume (let's call it Volume A) from the original instance
- **Attach** Volume A to the temporary instance
- **Modify a setting** will which cause the EC2Config service to generate a new password
- **Detach** Volume A from the temporary instance
- **Reattach** Volume A to the original instance
- **Boot** the original instance
- Use the standard "**Get Windows Password**" process to retrieve the new password

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the feedback!